# Box2d rope - NOT fixed length

Tags: java, box2d

I am creating game with box2d physics, I have a crane with rope attached to it, something like that (example)

[image]

What I am trying to achieve is to let player to fold or unfold line (to certain limits obviously) currently I am only able to create fixed length rope, which is limiting my game a little bit.

How could I achieve it? I had couple of ideas, but are rather not good ones, like recreating rope all the time, but it would just destroy my performance.

Comment: If you use a rope joint you can change the length any time without needing to recreate the joint all the time. Does the rope actually need to collide with anything? If not you could just draw a verlet integration style rope between the two endpoints.

Comment: It does not really have to collide with anything, that would be even cool if it would not collide, it just have to connect crane main arm, and things like magnet on the end of the rope to catch certain object, I will try to research about thing you mentioned, thank you.

Comment: @iforce2d - could you please give some more details about this verlet integration style rope - I was googling but could not find any reliable source of information, thanks.

Comment: Google for Advanced Character Physics by Thomas Jakobsen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I would check to see if that actually does ruin your performance.  You might be surprised by how fast it is.

If it does, one solution is to create an array of short ropes attached to one another (say 10).   This ia basically what a rope is anyway, you just need to hold on to the elements.

To make the rope be 6 units long, hide and collision disable the last 4 and attach the load to the end of the sixth rope segment.

Comment: Well, that is a good idea, but it is going to look nice? Anyway I will check this out, thank you for your tip.